# Браузер не видит изменения

Tags: css, netbeans, браузер

Здравствуйте! Я работаю в Netbeans. В нём же, в файле css изменяю код. Сохранил. Открыл в Notpad'е - изменения есть. Когда загружаю страницу - инспектирую елемент браузер(Chrome)  не видит изменения. В css коде инспектора изменений нет. Может кто сталкивался уже?

```
.add_to_basket  {
    background: url("/images/shelf.png") no-repeat center;
    color: #0f0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 39px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

не работает **display: block;**

Comment: CTRL+F5 в браузере

Comment: Я наслышан был о Stak'е, но не думал что ТАК БЫСТРО! Спасибо!

Comment: @Дмитрий если вам помог ответ, отметьте его решением(галка под цифрой слева от ответа).

Comment: в хроме еще можно `CTRL+R`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> в браузере
или в URL подключения css номер версии  например `site.css?ver=345` меняем каждый раз при обновлении файла css.

Comment: CTRL+F5 помог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

На данный момент, чтобы полностью перезагрузить страницу в Хроме, нужно:

1. Нажать Ctrl+Shift+i (переход в режим "Просмотреть код")
2. Нажать и удерживать значок обновления страницы (верхний-левый угол - круглая стрелка), пока не выпадет меню, и выбрать "Очистка кеша и аппаратная перезагрузка".